# obfuscating filenames in python

Tags: python, security, obfuscation

I have an app that handles some sensitive files. When the app runs, it decrypts each file for about a second then re-encrypts it once its done with it.

I would like to hide the filename itself, on top of encrypting the content. I have managed to do this reliably on my mac using a simple caesar-cipher style shifting function, as follows:

Obfuscation function (shifts characters over by 5 places):

```
def obs_filename(text, places=5):
    text = text.replace(' ', '')
    return ''.join(chr(ord(char) + places) for char in text)
```

Usage usage:

```
  for file in files:
      file_name = os.path.basename(file)
      new_file_name=deobs_filename(file_name)
      os.rename(folder+"/"+file, folder+"/"+new_file_name)
```

To de-obfuscate the function is just reversed to shift the other way.

```
    def deobs_filename(text, places=5):
    text = text.replace(' ', '')
    return ''.join(chr(ord(char) - places) for char in text)
```

The problem is that this seems to be causing errors in windows (I suspect some form of allowed filename character error, although the function just fails and no error is shown in the cmd line). The reason I suspect an error in the allowed characters in windows is that some of the files are getting renamed, then it fails partway through.

Hoping someone has a better way of obfuscating the filename, or possibly editing the function to only allow alphabet characters instead of all characters?

Comment: Why does the deobfuscation function remove spaces? The obfuscation function removed spaces, so there won't be any to remove. You'd ideally want to add the spaces back, but there's no way to know where they were.

Comment: Could just just shift letters, and wrap them around in the alphabet? Then you won't have to worry about invalid characters.

Comment: Why don't you just put the decrypted data in a temporary file instead of renaming the original file? The temporary filename won't have any meaning.

Comment: If you're running on a POSIX system (Unix/Linux), you might want to try experimenting with creating a working file and removing it from the directory while you still have the file open, but before you write any data to it. If Python allows you to do that, you'll have a secure working file that's hard to find and will automatically be cleaned up if you crash.  As long has you have the file handle open you'll have access to your data.  And once you close it, the file is gone (although the data might still be on disk somewhere if you didn't overwrite it.)

Comment: (cont)  There's a reason why allowing a file to be deleted while it's still open actually is a **good** idea.

Comment: The removal of spaces was just an oversight, not intentional to do that, although it didn't affect the functionality. I could probably do it with a container? Sounds more complicated to me since I'm not too familiar working with containers/pickled files etc. This was my first thought for hiding the filename

Comment: Windows has much less inclusive rules about characters permitted in filenames and a naive Caesar cypher may very well be running foul of those rules: no `<  >   :   "  /   \  |  ? *`; and there are also rules about trailing dots and spaces. It might be better to generate a filename temporarily in preference to obfuscating the real one.

Comment: Are you sure decrypting the file is really necessary? What do you do with the decrypted files, if this part is also implemented in your Python code, then better decrypt the data on-the-fly and process it block by block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this for the time being to get around the windows issue, is just turning the filenames to hex so they don't mean anything. Not a great way to secure them, and probably even worse than the cesar cipher, but at least it works. Still looking for a better option to hide the filenames if someone has one.

Obsfuscate:

```
    def obs_filename(fname):
    string = fname.encode('utf-8').hex()
    return string
```

Deobfuscate:

```
    def deobs_filename(fname):
    string=codecs.decode(fname, "hex")  
    new_file_name=(str(string,'utf-8'))
```

This works on both macos and windows, and serves the purpose of not knowing what you're looking at at first glance.