# How to obfuscate windows long filenames without exceeding max length

Tags: windows, unicode, filenames, ntfs

While backing up sensitive files between Windows 10 and SMB shares, I want to obfuscate the filenames. The source FS is NTFS and I don't want to change the filesystem on the source or the target. I've already found a very fast way to reversibly obfuscate the contents of the files.

I believe windows filenames are Unicode or UTF-16. A survey of the filenames shows they currently use about 400 different characters spread throughout the Unicode range but the solution must allow for any legal filename character.

Mapping the characters between two lists would require an array of ~150,000 possible values. Mathematically translating each character would risk falling on one of the famous list of characters not allowed in a filename, `:/?<>\¦,` etc. B64 encoding, in order to cover the Unicode range would double-ish the length of the filename.

Has anyone run into a known effective method for this or done this before?

I started off with a scheme to B64 encode the filenames using URL safe encoding but then realized a solid UTF-16 to Base 64 translation would vastly increase the length of the filenames.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [obfuscating filenames in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713371/obfuscating-filenames-in-python)

Comment: If the file-name is already sensitive what about the file content? If you backup the files you could include the file-name in the file data and use randomly generated file names.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - The number one solution proposed in the article, "obfuscating filenames in python" vastly increases the filename length. I thoroughly studied that article before asking this question.

Comment: @Robert - Storing the filename in the contents of the file itself sounds interesting but my current method of obfuscating the contents is extremely fast because it doesn't change the length of the data or overwrite more than a small fraction of the file, and there are terabytes of data to back up. I'm sure it would unnecessarily increase the time it takes to run.

Comment: **Are you sure you are developing a backup software and not a ransomware system?** A backup tool that obfuscates file content is IMHO a tool nobody needs. If you want to protect backup, data encrypt it properly and save additional integrity data.

Comment: @Robert - Yes, I'm sure. I've tested a couple of encryption methods and it **takes far too long**. It's for an offsite backup of business data and it's just to make sure the external drives are not easily read in the event the drives are stolen or something. Obscurity will go a long way in protecting it.

Comment: Max file path size can be worked around with stuff like extended `\\?\ ` paths. It depends how obfuscated you want them to be, and your workflow. It would be simple to generate random names, then save a list of `original.name=new.name` to a database, or just a file in the same folder

Comment: If you are encrypting while you copy, the time difference should be negligible compared to disk write speeds. For that much business data, you should consider actual backup software that will do all that for you, plus compression, differential, dedupe, etc.

Comment: When those drives are written you should simply use VeraCrypt to fully encrypt them. Modern CPUs can encrypted data using AES faster than any HDD and even most SSD can write and the CPU usage is still low as AES is implemented in hardware (if you use the correct AES library - VeraCrypt does).

Comment: @Robert - The VeraCrypt option sounds tempting. In the long run, that's probably a good answer. I'm thinking of swapping out the current NAS utility box from Windows to Arch or Centos and I'm thinking setting up VeraCrypt would be a lot easier on a Linux box. The dependencies and steps listed for compiling on Windows sounds more involved than just buckling down and writing a Python script that would finesse a mathematical character mapping for UTF-16 that avoids forbidden characters. I'll definitely consider it for the future though.

Comment: @WDRev "*Obscurity will go a long way in protecting it*" - [security through obscurity is not real security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).